# Pandas: concatenate dataframe with distance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, euclidean-distance

I tried to concatenate two Pandas DataFrames, but it concatenates wrong.

Initial dataset looks like:

```
df
>>>
            well    qoil    cum_oil         wct     top_perf    bot_perf    st  x       y
    5233    101     259     3.684131e+05    97      -2352.13    -2359.12    0   517228  5931024
    12786   102     3495    1.369303e+06    5.47    -2352.92    -2566.81    0   517192  5927187
    13062   103     2691    1.353718e+06    0.5     -2377.93    -2581.73    0   517731  5926430
    . . . .
65 rows × 9 columns
```

Then I generate a Euclidean distance between every well from x and y coordinates (last two columns):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('euclidean')
loc = pd.DataFrame(dist.pairwise(df[['x','y']].to_numpy()),
             columns=df.well.unique(), index=df.well.unique())
```

and receive 65x65 matrix (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame type) where contains the distance between every well

```
loc
>>>
    101         102         103         . . . 
101 0.000000    152.278917  270.835312  . . .
102 151.278917  0.000000    326.310146  . . .
103 270.835312  346.310146  0.000000    . . .
. . .
```

Then I drop extra columns and concatenate two dataframes:

```
df_train_prep = df.drop(['well', 'wct', 'x', 'y'], axis=1)
df2 = pd.concat([df_train_prep, loc], axis=1)
```

As a result I receive not 65 rows x (9 + 65) columns dataframe but **130 rows × 70 columns df** like:

```
df2
>>>
    qoil    cum_oil     top_perf    bot_perf    st  101 102 103 . . .
236 0.001   542681.0    -2427.66    -2539.25    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 
258 2291    292356.0    -2537.38    -2657.02    1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 
537 3290    237163.0    -2714.32    -2741.49    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
101 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.000000    157.278917  280.835312  323.423701  ...
102 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 154.278917  0.000000    356.310146  210.348200  518.786999  ...
```

It looks like some data concatenate in the right but some moved to the bottom. Moreover, strange NaN value popped up.
Please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dummy Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5), 'y': range(5)})

# Pairewice euclidean distances 
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
distance = pd.DataFrame(euclidean_distances(df[['x', 'y']]))

# Concatenate
df = pd.concat([df, distance], axis=1)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
    x   y   0           1           2           3           4
0   0   0   0.000000    1.414214    2.828427    4.242641    5.656854
1   1   1   1.414214    0.000000    1.414214    2.828427    4.242641
2   2   2   2.828427    1.414214    0.000000    1.414214    2.828427
3   3   3   4.242641    2.828427    1.414214    0.000000    1.414214
4   4   4   5.656854    4.242641    2.828427    1.414214    0.000000
```

As you can see the parewise distance is a symmetric matrix.